# Update two fields with linq and DataSet

Tags: c#, linq

I need update two fields in my Databse. These are rules:
1) If these fields(DT_GERACAO and BL_RELATORIO) are null, so I update.

Well, my Issue is that my application is a Console Application. I do not have a context, so I do not get use a linq or lambda expression.

See below my complete code.

```
public static void Emitir()
        {
            //Relatório com DataSource = ORACLE
            dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable dtPlanoMedico = new dsPlanoMedico.PLANO_MEDICODataTable();
            dsPlanoMedico.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIODataTable dtSolicRel = new dsPlanoMedico.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIODataTable();

            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.PLANO_MEDICOTableAdapter();
            dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIOTableAdapter solic_adapt = new dsPlanoMedicoTableAdapters.POC_SOLIC_RELATORIOTableAdapter();

            adapt.Fill(dtPlanoMedico);
            solic_adapt.Fill(dtSolicRel);
            //dtPlanoMedico.Where(i => i.IND_REGULAMENTADO == "S");

            var dv = new System.Data.DataView(dtPlanoMedico);
            dv.RowFilter = "IND_REGULAMENTADO LIKE 'N' and TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";
            //dv.RowFilter = "TIPO_REGISTRO_ANS LIKE 'D'";

            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("dsDados", dv);
            ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();

            viewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
            viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportBD.rdlc";
            //viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter("Regulamentado", "S"));
            viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);

            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string encoding = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;

            byte[] bytesPDF = viewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsPDF = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.pdf", FileMode.Create);
            fsPDF.Write(bytesPDF, 0, bytesPDF.Length);
            fsPDF.Close();
            fsPDF.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesExcel = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Excel", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsExcel = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.xls", FileMode.Create);
            fsExcel.Write(bytesExcel, 0, bytesExcel.Length);
            fsExcel.Close();
            fsExcel.Dispose();

            byte[] bytesWord = viewer.LocalReport.Render("Word", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);
            FileStream fsWord = new FileStream("c:\\Relatemp\\report.doc", FileMode.Create);
            fsWord.Write(bytesWord, 0, bytesWord.Length);
            fsWord.Close();
            fsWord.Dispose();

        }
```

I tryed this, but do not work:

```
var query = dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable()
            .Where(x => x.DT_GERACAO == null && x.BL_RELATORIO == null).First();

            query.BL_RELATORIO = bytesPDF;
            query.DT_GERACAO = DateTime.Now;

            solic_adapt.Update(query);

            }
```

What do I do?

EDIT

I wrote this code, but I don't to update these fileds:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

DataTable dtRel = ds.Tables["POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO"];

var query = dtRel.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(rel => new
            {
                dtGeracao = rel.Field<DateTime>("DT_GERACAO"),
                binario   = rel.Field<byte[]>("BL_RELATORIO")
            });
```

I tryed other code, but still having erros. The issue is on this line:

```
if(query.BL_RELATORIO == null && query.DT_GERACAO == null)
```

See my code below.

```
var query = (from i in dtSolicRel
                         //where i.DT_GERACAO == null && i.BL_RELATORIO == null
                         select i).ToList().First();

            if(query.BL_RELATORIO == null && query.DT_GERACAO == null)
            {
                query.BL_RELATORIO = bytesPDF;
                query.DT_GERACAO = DateTime.Now;
                solic_adapt.Update(query);
            }
```

I resolved this way

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO"];

            var rowsWithAccount = (from row in dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable()
                                  where row.Field<object>("DT_GERACAO") == null && row.Field<object>("BL_RELATORIO") == null
                                  select row).First();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                rowsWithAccount.SetField("DT_GERACAO", DateTime.Now);
                rowsWithAccount.SetField("BL_RELATORIO", bytesPDF);
                solic_adapt.Update(rowsWithAccount);
            }
```

I answered, but the response disappeared, then I decided to edit the post.

Comment: Does not work means what?

Comment: @pkt what does this mean `I do not have a context, so I do not get use a linq or lambda expression.` why can't you use it.. all you need to do is add 
`using System.Linq;` to your header long with 
`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;`

Comment: @MethodMan, I know, I have a difficult to work with linq. I Always worked with DBContext or DBSet<>, but with DataSet, is first time. I do not a largest experience with linq and lambda.

Comment: I will post something and let me know if this fixes your issue. also where are you filling the the data in your `EDIT`

Comment: DT_GERACAO and BL_RELATORIO are null both. My code do not work, because are null both fields.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you `Fill` the DataTable properly you can do the following

```
DataTable dtRel = new DataTable();
var queryRows = (from dRow in dtRel.AsEnumerable()
                    select new 
                    { 
                       dtGeracao = dRow.Field<DateTime>("DT_GERACAO"),
                       binario   = dRow.Field<byte[]>("BL_RELATORIO")
                    });
```

Comment: But I need update DT_GERACAO with DateTime.Now() and BL_RELATORIO with the file: bytesPDF. How can I do?

Comment: set `dtGeracao =  DateTime.Now;`

Answer (score 0):

I did so and worked:

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            DataTable dt = ds.Tables["POC_SOLIC_RELATORIO"];

            var rowsWithAccount = (from row in dtSolicRel.AsEnumerable()
                                  where row.Field<object>("DT_GERACAO") == null && row.Field<object>("BL_RELATORIO") == null
                                  select row);

            foreach (DataRow row in rowsWithAccount)
            {
                row.SetField("DT_GERACAO", DateTime.Now);
                row.SetField("BL_RELATORIO", bytesPDF);
                solic_adapt.Update(row);
            }
```